# How can i get list of values from array in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have `array` such as below

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 5)
```

In which `2,4,5` is value and i need only list of value like `[2,4,5]` is it possible in laravel??

Comment: Use `implode(',', $array);` for output as `[2,4,5]`. Use this @hiren it helps you!! Or you can use `foreach` loop to get only values as a `key=>value` pair!

Comment: Is it helps you?? If yes i can post my answer and please accept it ok?

Answer (score 0):

```
$list=[];
$arr=array( 0=> 2,1 => 4,2 => 5);// This is the original array
foreach($arr as $k=>$v ){
    array_push($list,$v);
     }
// Now,$list is what you need! [2,4,5]
```

I don't think this question is about laravel, this is basic knowledge of PHP array!

Comment: This is the official document of [PHP Array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Got list using below command.

```
 implode(',', $array);
```